# How to split up a string on multiple delimiters but only capture some?

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string on any combination of delimiters I provide. For example, if the string is:

```
s = 'This, I think,., کباب MAKES , some sense '
```

And the delimiters are `\.`, `,`, and `\s`. However I want to capture all delimiters except whitespace `\s`. The output should be:

```
['This', ',', 'I', 'think', ',.,', 'کباب', 'MAKES', ',', 'some', 'sense']
```

My solution so far is is using the `re` module:

```
pattern = '([\.,\s]+)'  
re.split(pattern, s)
```

However, this captures whitespace as well. I have tried using other patterns like `[(\.)(,)\s]+` but they don't work.

*Edit*: @PadraicCunningham made an astute observation. For delimiters like `Some text ,. , some more text`, I'd only want to remove leading and trailing whitespace from `,. ,` and not whitespace within.

Comment: Could you just remove the `\s` initially?

Comment: What about removing the whitespace from strings resulting from the captured result? This is not a generalized solution to the problem and it ought to 'work' here due to the simple nature of the regex.

Comment: @eavidan But then it does not split on whitespace. That way I'd have to run `re.split('\s', ...)` on each element of the returned list from the first split.

Comment: @user2864740 That was going to be my last resort. I wanted to know if there is a simpler/quicker way to go about it.

Comment: @hazrmard then how about splitting as your originally have, and then remove the whitespace?

Comment: What is the correct output for `'This, I think, ., کباب MAKES , some sense '`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham nice catch there. I'd only like to remove only leading and trailing whitespace from `, ., `. I'll put this in an edit in my quesstion.

Comment: I guess the solution using `strip()` by RomanPerekhrest is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach would be the most simple one, I suppose ...

```
s = 'This, I think,., کباب MAKES , some sense '
pattern = '([\.,\s]+)'
splitted = [i.strip() for i in re.split(pattern, s) if i.strip()]
```

The output:

```
['This', ',', 'I', 'think', ',.,', 'کباب', 'MAKES', ',', 'some', 'sense']
```

Comment: `if i.strip()` is sufficient to check for an empty string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, exactly, cause after splitting we have them in the result : `... ' , ', 'some', ' ', 'sense', ' '`. Single spaces and trailing spaces should be filtered out

Comment: `strip()` will not remove whitespace embedded between other delimiters. I guess you must remove them explicitly by something like `[i for i in [re.sub(r'\s', '', i) for i in re.split(r'([,.\s]+)', s)] if len(i) > 0]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks for the edit(little optimization)

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** According to the new edit on the question, I've improved my old regex. The new one is quite long but trust me, it's work!

I suggest a pattern below as a delimiter of the function `re.split()`:

```
(?<![,\.\ ])(?=[,\.]+)|(?<=[,\.])(?![,\.\ ])|(?<=[,\.])\ +(?![,\.\ ])|(?<![,\.\ ])\ +(?=[,\.][,\.\ ]+)|(?<![,\.\ ])\ +(?![,\.\ ])
```

My workaround here doesn't require any pre/post space modification. The thing that make regex work is about how you order the regex expressions with `or`. My cursory strategy is any patterns that dealing with a space-leading will be evaluated last.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eW8rZ6/3)

**Additional**

According to @revo's comment he provided an another shorten version of mine which is

```
\s+(?=[^.,\s])|\b(?:\s+|(?=[,.]))|(?<=[,.])\b
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eW8rZ6/5)

Comment: Still substitutes on `Some text ,. , some`. See OP's edit.

Comment: @Bharel please check it out.

Comment: You could shorten your regex to [this](https://regex101.com/r/eW8rZ6/5).

Answer (score 0):

*Update based on OP's last edit*

Python 3.*:

```
list(filter(None, re.split('([.,]+(?:\s+[.,]+)*)|\s', s)))
```

Output:

```
['This', ',', 'I', 'think', ',.,', 'کباب', 'MAKES', ',', 'some', 'sense']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the most efficient option regarding memory, and really efficient regarding computation time:

```
import re
from itertools import chain
from operator import methodcaller

input_str = 'This, I think,., ???? MAKES , some sense '

iterator = filter(None,  # Filter out all 'None's
                  chain.from_iterable(  # Flatten the tuples into one long iterable
                    map(methodcaller("groups"),  # Take the groups from each match.
                        re.finditer("(.*?)(?:([\.,]+)|\s+|$)", input_str))))

# If you want a list:
list(iterator)
```

Comment: `'This, I think, ., ???? MAKES , some sense '` and it breaks, check the OP's edit.

Comment: I did not know you can capture groups in `re.split()`. Good to know.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fixed it. Btw, it's still more efficient regarding memory, as it takes 1/3 of the accepted solution.

Comment: The `([\.,]+)` is the problem, the OP needs to preserve whitespace that falls between the two delimiters.  i.e `"foo , , ba"r -> ["foo", ",  .", "bar"]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham whaaaaa since when?